# POSTing JSON data with cURL in PHP 5

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to POST some JSON data using cURL, but I'm having an issue setting the headers.

My current code looks like so:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://secure.example.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
]);

if (!$result = curl_exec($ch))
{
    echo 'Failed: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

This code works fine when testing using localhost (PHP 7). However, our web server only runs PHP 5, and as such, the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option is not supported.

When I keep it in my code, I get a "500 Internal Error".
When I take it out, my `curl_exec()` does not run, and I received the error message "Failed: " but with no `curl_error()` being displayed.

Is there any way to set cURL to expect JSON data without this option?

Comment: What cURL version do you have on the web server?

Comment: if you get a 500, you go look at the server's error log for details.

Comment: Actually, the statement *`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option is not supported in PHP 5* is false.

Comment: Who said `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is not supported by PHP 5?

Comment: I was looking here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php - "Available since PHP 7.0.7"

Comment: Look to be running cURL 7.9.17

Comment: @mpdc You looked wrong. That information is for `CURLOPT_HEADEROPT` , not `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
]);
```

With

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));
```

PHP 5.4+ support the new array syntax of `[]`, but PHP < 5.4 needs array()

Short array syntax support was added in PHP 5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are getting is not about `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. It's been in PHP for ages.

But the new array syntax `[]` that was added in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.new-features.php).

Change your code to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));
```

and it will work fine.